# Footer in positioning other than absolute or fixed?

Tags: css

I've set up my problem [here](http://www.scottmccarthydesign.com/example223.html).

I have 2 divs, each outlined with a black border. One is my content div (containing text), with height set to 600px; The other div, containing a banner image, I'd like to use as my page's footer. I am able to do this in absolute positioning by simply marking the div with "bottom: 25px." However, what I'm hoping to do is to make the footer div "stop" when it collides with the content div as you shrink the size of your browser window.

Any ideas? Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it. Got the technique from http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/. He adds an extra "push" div but I used the wrapper's padding bottom to serve the same function (no need for empty DIVs).

Here's an example (you can view it at http://ve.savantcoding.com/example.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample footer</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    #wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -200px; /* bottom margin is negative footer height */
    }
    #content {
        padding-bottom: 200px /* bottom padding is footer height */
    }
    #footer {
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">your content</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">your banner</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the response. So I tried to implement the coding example you gave me, but I can't seem to get it to work? I've posted my updated example here: http://www.scottmccarthydesign.com/example223.html Thanks!

Comment: hey, easy fix. You're missing that important on height: auto.

Comment: @user820114 also if you're wondering why you have vertical scrollbars on that example page, it's due to the top margin on content's first `<p>`. Setting that to `<p style="margin-top: 0;">` should get rid of it. Also, don't forget the exclamation in `height: auto !important`.